# What is the syntax, if any, of unicode characters in Common Lisp?

Tags: unicode, syntax, common-lisp

Are there any syntax for unicode characters in Common Lisp? Like `\u03B1` in Java?

Maybe something like `#\U+03B1`, or something similar?

Comment: The Common Lisp standard predates Unicode. Therefore this depends on implementation. Usually it’s `#\Full_name_of_unicode_character`

Comment: Did you try typing `#\U+03b1`? because that works in SBCL.

Comment: See https://github.com/edicl/cl-unicode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The uber-portable way is `#.(code-char X)` which will produce the
Unicode char with the given numeric code `X` (provided that the implementation actually uses Unicode - which the ANSI standard does not require - and, indeed, all implementations that go beyond ASCII - which is *not* mandated either! - *do* use Unicode).

If you know the Unicode *name* of the character, you can also use the [`#\`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dha.htm) syntax:

```
(char= (code-char 12345) #\HANGZHOU_NUMERAL_TWENTY)
T
```

Implementations often define additional Unicode character syntax, e.g.:

- [`#\Code<decimal>`](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/sharpsign.html#sharpsign-backslash) in [CLISP](http://clisp.org).
- `#\U+0<hex>` in [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/).

See:

- [`code-char`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_code_c.htm)
- [`*read-eval*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_rd_eva.htm)
- [Sharpsign Dot](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhf.htm)

Comment: Only if the implementation chooses UNICODE as internal coding system, I think?

Comment: @Svante: indeed, but all implementations that go beyond ASCII - which is not mandated either! - do use Unicode.